# Yum command to downgrade packages

Tags: yum, rpm, awk, syntax

I need to downgrade php on a server and found the command below.  Something seems to be wrong with the syntax.

```
yum downgrade $(rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME} " | \
            grep -v ioncube | grep ^php | awk '{print $1"-5.2.17"}')
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Need to pass a list of pkgs to downgrade
usage: yum [options] COMMAND
```

Comment: This generate error because rpm output is just single long line (you replace standard \n in output with just " "), so next `grep ^php` produce empty output - if you use just `rpm -qa` then this method will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My situation might a little specific but here is what worked for me.  I am sure there is a better way but....

I added the atomic repo.
wget -qq -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | /bin/bash

Sent all the installed programs to a file.
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME} "> installed

Filtered the results to a new file with just the apps that I needed.  The grep -v command did not work as I thought it would.  I needed to exclude the phpioncube and I thought the -v would do it but it still showed up the file.  I manually deleted it.
grep -v ioncube installed |grep php installed>phpapps

I knew the specific version that I wanted to downgrade to so I appended it to each package name and ran the following command.
yum downgrade install php-pdo-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-pecl-memcached-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-xml-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-pecl-memcache-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-pear-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-mcrypt-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-xmlrpc-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-snmp-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-odbc-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-ldap-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-common-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-mysql-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-gd-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-mbstring-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-cli-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-devel-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-pecl-zip-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-imap-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-ncurses-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64 php-mhash-5.2.17-1.el6.art.x86_64

This got me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making the command line far too complicated:

```
sudo yum downgrade php-*
```

I don't think that is going to get you what you want though.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This actually led me to what I ended up doing.